# Trying to install most voip api for python 2.7 on ubuntu 14.04 gives several unknown gnu linux errors

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

I've tried to install using the steps given on the most voip documentation, using the steps:

1. Download the last svn revision from http://svn.pjsip.org/repos/pjproject/trunk/ (revision 4818 works well). (tar.gz and zip archives don’t compile!)
2. ./configure CFLAGS=’-fPIC’
3. make dep
4. make
5. sudo make install
6. cd pjsip-apps/src/python/
7. sudo python setup.py install

But, on step 4, I get errors like:

```
 #include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [output/pjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/alsa_dev.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/students/Desktop/trunk/pjmedia/build'
make[1]: *** [libpjmedia-audiodev-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu.a] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/students/Desktop/trunk/pjmedia/build'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

This is just one of the several similar errors that I get

Answer (score 1):

By [searching ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?lang=en&suite=trusty&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=asoundlib.h) it seems the following should resolve these errors:

```
sudo apt install libasound2-dev
```

This will install the dev headers that are being `#include`d in the file being compiled